# Recreate this image in Latex

Tags: matrices, arrays, decorations

Can anyone please guide me in how I can recreate this image in Latex ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Hello, I was initially thinking to create this using tables but I have no idea how to create the 45 degree lines and give them labels. I would appreciate if I can get some guidance here.

Comment: You should edit your post and explain the image you gave, what exactly is it that you want and try giving a MWE if possible to see how much you tried.

Comment: Gives also the way to fill the cells. Is it automatable? If it is the package `nicematrix` should be a good choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!! As your image is quite repetitive you can draw this with `\foreach` commands. Something like this (I left the labels for you).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid [step=0.5] (10,11); 
\draw[thin,gray]  (0,0) grid (10,11);
\foreach\i in {1,...,10} \foreach\j in {1,...,11}
{%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\ii{Mod(\i,2)}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\jj{Mod(\j+1,2)}
  \node at (\i-0.5,\j-0.5) {$\ii\jj$};
}
\draw[mygreen] (0,1)   -- (10,11);
\draw          (0,0.5) -- (10,10.5);
\draw[red]     (0,0)   -- (10,10);
\foreach\i in {1,...,10}
{%
  \fill[mygreen,opacity=0.3] (\i-1,\i-0.5) |- (\i-0.5,\i) -- cycle;
  \fill[red    ,opacity=0.3] (\i-0.5,\i)   -| (\i,\i+0.5) -- cycle;
}
\foreach\i in {1,3,...,11} \foreach\j in {1,...,4}
{%
  \ifnum\i < 11
    \draw (\i-0.125+0.1*\j+0.25,5.875) --++ (0.25,0.25);
  \fi
  \draw (4.875,\i-0.125+0.1*\j-0.75) --++ (0.25,0.25);
}
\node at (10,6) [right] {$X_1$};
\node at (5,11) [above] {$X_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TeX SE. Here is something for you to start with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{NiceMatrix}[light-syntax,hvlines]
  10 00 10 00 10 00 10 00 10 00 10 ;
  11 01 11 01 11 01 11 01 11 01 11 ;
  10 00 10 00 10 00 10 00 10 00 10 ;
  \vdots ;
  10 00 10 00 10 00 10 00 10 00 10 ;
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{ \cell } { mm } {
    \int_mod:nn{ #2 }{ 2 } \int_mod:nn{ \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } }{ 2 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\AutoNiceMatrix[hvlines]{11-11}{\cell{\arabic{iRow}}{\arabic{jCol}}}$

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

It remains to add the decorations.